# OpenAPI Generator `typescript-fetch` vs `typescript-node` vs `typescript-axios`

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, fetch, openapi-generator

I see three options to choose from for my TypeScript project:

1. [typescript-axios](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-axios/)
2. [typescript-fetch](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-fetch/)
3. [typescript-node](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-node/)

I don't have any specific preference if it comes to `axios` vs `fetch`. I'm rather trying to figure out what generator is the most stable and maintained one.

I tried to compare open and closed issues in the [project's repository](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) but couldn't come up with a clear answer to my question: What should I choose and why?

UPDATE:

By now I tried `typescript-axios`, `typescript-fetch` and, thanks to the bellow answer `typescript`.

`typescript` didn't work very well with our specs. Seems like a couple of features are not yet implemented. By the time of writing it is was in beta state.

`typescript-axios` as well as `typescript-fetch` appeared to be very stable and very similar. The API is almost the same. Both generated all our specs without any issue and the usage is pretty straight forward.

We ended up using `typescript-axios` because `fetch` doesn't raise errors automatically. That was really the only advantage (for us) and not a characteristic of `typescript-fetch` but of the `fetch` API itself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/802), it seems the [typescrypt](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript) generator is going to be a more maintainable replacement than the generators you proposed. While it is currently flagged as 'experimental', I believe it will become a more solid option in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

### typescript-axios

I recommend this one now because of it seems to be maintained relatively well and works.

Drawback is external dependency. Especially now because node 18 support fetch natively and it is recommended method of sending requests. But `axios` take care about response status codes when decide if result should be treated as response or exception.

### typescript-fetch

I tried it and would use but it have few bugs. Eg no support for `anyOf`.

You can [compare example of code generated](https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/pull/348#issuecomment-1509676513) by axios and fetch generators.

### typescript-node

Not recommend because it use `request` that is depreciated few years ago.

https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

### openapi-generator-plus

If you are early adopter you can check also generators proposed by

https://github.com/karlvr/openapi-generator-plus

it is much worse documented but propose better architectural pattern. Currently 6 of 15 generators for it support typescript

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Aopenapi-generator-plus-generator%20%26%20typescript

Answer (score 0):

There’s now [openapi-fetch](https://github.com/drwpow/openapi-fetch) which automatically picks up your OpenAPI schema with very little config. And is lightweight and performant.